# When is UndecidableInstances safe? Some general questions regarding the GHC extension

Tags: haskell, ghc

I know of [the documentation for -XUndecidableInstances](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#undecidable-instances), but I thought I'd ask for an elaboration.

Suppose I have two multi-parameter typeclasses (allowed with [-XMultiParamTypeClasses](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#id3172593))

```
class Foo a b
class Goo a b
```

Now, suppose I have a parameterized data type

```
data Bar a b
```

which I want to make an instance of `Foo` when one of its parameters is part of an instance of `Goo`. I'm not sure the previous sentence uses exact terminology, so here's what I want to write:

```
instance (Goo c d) => Foo d (Bar a d)
```

I'm not allowed to without the `UndecidableInstances` extension. Am I correct in thinking this is because the instance doesn't refer to the `c` type?

Should I...

1. Just enable the extension? Can somebody elaborate on what kinds of trouble it can get me into?
2. Add another parameter to `Foo`, so that  the last instance declaration becomes something like `Foo c d (Bar a d)`? A problem with this is that I might have other instances of `Foo` that never make any reference to any such "fourth type parameter" (i.e. there are instances of the form `instance Foo A B` in unrelated parts of my code), so these would break. I'd rather fix my instance, not my class.
3. Create a new class `FooGoo` with enough parameters? I would feel like I'm repeating myself in that case, but at least I wouldn't break unrelated classes.

Does anyone have any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking this is because the instance doesn't refer to the c type?

Yes, your code does not adhere to (from [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-rules)):

> For each assertion in the context: No
>   type variable has more occurrences in
>   the assertion than in the head

In general, you should be safe unless you add other instances that would, together, form a loop. Things only get really hairy (and compiler-dependent) when it comes to `OverlappingInstances`, and rightout evil when you go `IncoherentInstances`.

Without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish it's hard to give sound design advice, but the first thing to check is whether you really, really need to have c as a parameter to Goo. You might be able to do express what you want to accomplish like this:

```
class Goo d where
    bar :: d c -> Int
    baz :: Quux c => d c -> Int
```

Comment: Thanks. This brings some degree of clarification.

Comment: I think also the `Goo c d` constraint would make the `Foo d (Bar a d)` instance unusable unless `Goo` has a functional dependency `d -> c` - otherwise, how does the compiler decide which `Goo` instance to use?  If all `Goo` instances have `c` as a type variable not occurring in `d`, then @barsoap's suggestion to drop that type parameter is the way to go.