# Haskell type family instance with type constraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints, type-families, type-level-computation

I am trying to represent expressions with type families, but I cannot seem to figure out how to write the constraints that I want, and I'm starting to feel like it's just not possible.  Here is my code:

```
class Evaluable c where
    type Return c :: *
    evaluate :: c -> Return c

data Negate n = Negate n

instance (Evaluable n, Return n ~ Int) => Evaluable (Negate n) where
    type Return (Negate n) = Return n
    evaluate (Negate n) = negate (evaluate n)
```

This all compiles fine, but it doesn't express exactly what I want. In the constraints of the `Negate` instance of `Evaluable`, I say that the return type of the expression inside `Negate` must be an `Int` (with `Return n ~ Int`) so that I can call negate on it, but that is too restrictive. The return type actually only needs to be an instance of the `Num` type class which has the `negate` function. That way `Double`s, `Integer`s, or any other instance of `Num` could also be negated and not just `Int`s. But I can't just write

```
Return n ~ Num
```

instead because `Num` is a type class and `Return n` is a type.  I also cannot put

```
Num (Return n)
```

instead because `Return n` is a type not a type variable.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with Haskell? If not, should it be, or am I misunderstanding some theory behind it? I feel like Java could add a constraint like this. Let me know if this question could be clearer.

Edit: Thanks guys, the responses are helping and are getting at what I suspected. It appears that the type checker isn't able to handle what I'd like to do without UndecidableInstances, so my question is, is what I'd like to express really undecidable? It is to the Haskell compiler, but is it in general? i.e. could a constraint even exist that means "check that Return n is an instance of Num" which is decidable to a more advanced type checker?

Comment: btw, didn't GHC ever recommend a language extension, such as e.g. `FlexibleContexts` or something else, during your trial and error process? because I'm quite sure it did — just a side-note on the _"is this even possible with Haskell"_ bit.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you can do exactly what you mentioned:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Evaluable c where
    type Return c :: *
    evaluate :: c -> Return c

data Negate n = Negate n

instance (Evaluable n, Num (Return n)) => Evaluable (Negate n) where
    type Return (Negate n) = Return n
    evaluate (Negate n) = negate (evaluate n)
```

`Return n` certainly is a type, which can be an instance of a class just like `Int` can. Your confusion might be about what can be the argument of a constraint. The answer is "anything with the correct kind". The kind of `Int` is `*`, as is the kind of `Return n`. `Num` has kind `* -> Constraint`, so *anything* of kind `*` can be its argument. It perfectly legal (though vacuous) to write `Num Int` as a constraint, in the same way that `Num (a :: *)` is legal.

Comment: Right, I should have explained that I have already looked into this, but the FlexibleContexts and UndecidableInstances extensions make me nervous. I feel like they could come back to bite me in the end when adding more instances, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `FlexibleContexts` is completely safe, and simply allows non-type variables as type parameters. `UndecidableInstances` can cause non-termination during compilation if your instances form a loop (as the compiler cannot check this). For more info, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5017549/925978).

Comment: @user3773003: I want to say something stronger than Eric: I don't think it's reasonable to use `TypeFamilies` without `FlexibleContexts`, and probably not without `UndecidableInstances`! The non-flexible context rules were designed for a language without type families; it's no surprise they need extension. And since type families are type-level functions, it's no surprise that the (type-level) termination checker can get in the way, especially since it's not very smart; we don't have a termination checker at the value level, so `UndecidableInstances` gets us a similarly-expressive type level.

Comment: @user3773003 I consider `FlaxibleContexts` completely harmless, and I hope it will be included in the next Haskell standard. `UndecidableInstances` is also fine, albeit I can see some value in having to turn it on explcitly. OTOH, `Incoherent-` and `Overlapping-` instances are evil, and should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Eric's answer, let me suggest one possible alternative: using a functional dependency instead of a type family:

```
class EvaluableFD r c | c -> r where
  evaluate :: c -> r

data Negate n = Negate n

instance (EvaluableFD r n, Num r) => EvaluableFD r (Negate n) where
  evaluate (Negate n) = negate (evaluate n)
```

This makes it a bit easier to talk about the result type, I think. For instance, you can write

```
foo :: EvaluableFD Int a => Negate a -> Int
foo x = evaluate x + 12
```

You can also use `ConstraintKinds` to apply this partially (which is why I put the arguments in that funny-looking order):

```
type GivesInt = EvaluableFD Int
```

You could do this with your class as well, but it would be more annoying:

```
type GivesInt x = (Evaluable x, Result x ~ Int)
```

Comment: Yes, again something I should have mentioned that I tried in the original question.  This one too needs UndecidableInstances and also FlexibleInstances which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @user3773003, I'm not too optimistic that you can get what you want without these extensions. I could be missing something, of course.

Comment: @user3773003 There is literally no downside to `FlexibleInstances` and `UndecidableInstances` is also effectively harmless.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, Ekmett prefers to avoid flexible instances when possible (I think to improve instance resolution), but only when possible.