# Haskell instance with constraint

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to make a typeclass for signed numerical types. Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Sign = Negative | Zero | Positive
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

class Signed a where
  sign :: a -> Sign

instance Signed Integer where
  sign = undefined
```

This compiles, but I'd like to adapt this code to work on any `Integral a`.

```
instance (Integral a) => Signed a where
  sign = undefined
```

At which point it fails to compile.

I've checked [Haskell type family instance with type constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983019/haskell-type-family-instance-with-type-constraints), but that seems to be addressing a different problem from mine. I don't think
there's a syntax error, in my code.

Comment: You'd need to turn on `OverlappingInstances`, I think. On the other hand, I think putting `sign` in a class may be a mistake in this case - just define a top-level function `sign :: Integral a => a -> Sign`.

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't seem to change. `instance Signed Integer` still compiles, but `instance (Integral a) => ...` still fails.

Comment: OK, I put your code into a file and GHC told me I needed to turn on `FlexibleInstances` too. With that, it compiles right away. (GHC's error messages are usually quite specific about which extensions you need to turn on.)

Comment: You're right. It does tell me... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to compile your code produces the following error message:

```
sign.hs:9:26:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘Signed a’
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for ‘Signed a’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

As the compiler points out, you need to turn on `FlexibleInstances` as well as `UndecidableInstances`. GHC's error messages are usually quite specific, especially when you've forgotten to turn on a language extension. The following compiles right away:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Sign = Negative | Zero | Positive
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

class Signed a where
  sign :: a -> Sign

instance (Integral a) => Signed a where
  sign = undefined
```

However, I think the `Signed` class may be a mistake in this example. Defining a (non-overloaded) top-level function is much simpler, doesn't require `UndecidableInstances` (the need for which is often a design smell), and is more expressive of the *meaning* of your code: the "things you can get the sign of" are precisely the real numbers.

```
sign :: Real a => a -> Sign
sign x
    | x == 0 = Zero
    | x < 0 = Negative
    | otherwise = Positive
```

Comment: Thank you for giving such a helpful answer. Glad I can get rid of the typeclass and pragmas.